# inconsistent behaviour of javascript (particlesJS)

Tags: javascript, html, go

I am trying to make a login page with work. Below is the body of main html page (only body is shown to keep things concise):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-box">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" />
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-custom">Login</button>
            </div>  <!-- /.controls -->
        </div>   <!-- /#login-box -->
    </div>    <!-- /.container -->

    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"> </script>

    <script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
        console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });
    </script>

</body>
```

In addition to this I have a css and particles.json static files.

Everything works when I execute it on a web browser with apache2 as web server.

Then I take the exact same files and use it in a Golang program:

```
func main(){
    templates := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("../../templates/index.html"))
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        if err:= templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil) ; err != nil{
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        //fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to Gopherland")
    })
    http.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("style")))
    http.Handle("/js/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("style")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}
```

and it fails to parse particles.json file:

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

No other compile time or run time error is thrown by Go. This error appears in browser console. I have checked the validity of particles.json file.

Can someone help please?

Contents of particles.json:

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 5,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true,
  "config_demo": {
    "hide_card": false,
    "background_color": "#b61924",
    "background_image": "",
    "background_position": "50% 50%",
    "background_repeat": "no-repeat",
    "background_size": "cover"
  }
}
```

Comment: That error usually indicates the JSON is malformed and cannot be parsed. You do realize your sample is missing the closing script tag for the first tag...right?

Comment: What is the content of the `particles.json` file as served by Go? It must be malformed. Examining that file will probably be informative.

Comment: Hi Randy, Just checked my code that closing script tag is present there, I must have messed it up while pasting. Good spot though :)

Hi Flimzy, I can organize the js and css files later, at the moment I just need to get things working with Golang as backend.

Comment: I have updated particles.json file in the question. However, I have checked the validity of the file online and thing to note here is - that exact same file works with apache2 as web server.

Comment: Is that the contents _as served by Go_? Or the contents on your disk before serving it?

Comment: content on my disk but I am monitoring it on the firefox browser, and this file's status comes back as HTTP 200.

Comment: I'm not interested in the HTTP status. I'm interested in the content. What is the body of the `particles.json` response served by Go?

Comment: Sorry but how can I find this out?

Comment: You can either look at it in the details of the HTTP request in the Firefox console (well, I know you can in Chrome, I assume the same in FF), or you could fetch the same file using curl.

Comment: But the error message suggests that the file is being corrupted (it says there's an error in the first byte of the file). So if you look at that file, you'll probably see what's wrong with it.  It's probably serving the wrong file, or the file is being corrupted, perhaps due to escaping or some other extra processing being done.

Answer (score 2):

`http.HandleFunc("/",` is matching anything that doesn't match elsewhere, it's essentially a catch all as the `ServeMux` documentation states:

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash). Longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for paths beginning "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree.

Since it is trying to load `particles.json`, and there is no better match, it is loading your index page.

You need to add another route, something like:

```
http.HandleFunc("/particles.json", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   http.ServeFile(w, r, "./path/to/particles.json")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your invaluable comments. I did try every options suggested above but couldn't make the program to work until I figured out that I had a silly misconception (due to lack of knowledge of course) that "**/**" in: *http.HandleFunc("**/**", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)* is the root of my project folder i.e. the folder under which I had my ./src, ./bin, ./style/css/ and ./style/js/

However, that wasn't the case. I modified the code to this:

```
func main () {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000" , nil)
}
```

compiled and ran. Only to find that if I don't pass any path it was listing the "root" filesystem's contents like, /bin, /home. This was enough for me to understand that Go code is considering "/" filesystem's root and **NOT** project's root folder. 
I then updated **absolute** path of css and json file in my index.html and boom... It worked!

Thanks again for your help. It did help me a lot.